# Hidden numbers (hand drawn)

Tags: visual, geometry

I like doodling and had an idea based on a flash game, where numbers are hidden in a picture, and it's ended up better than i expected. So have fun with it. And if you can give feedback on it that highly appreciated.

Every whole number from 1 to 50 is appearing once in the picture below. Better quality picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpfqV.jpg).

Disclaimer: since it's hand drawn, besides my best efforts, there are some fake positive answers (where its kinda looks like a number, when its not supposed to be). But i think if you find the right answer, you know it is the right one.

Hint:

> There can be some answers which are not Arabic numbers.

[image]

Comment: can I use roman numerals? like XLV=45

Answer (score 2):

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, X, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, X, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, X, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, X, X, 36, 37, X, X, 40, X, X, X, 44, X, X, 47, 48, X, X

37 out of 50... hopefully more on the way!

> [image]

Comment: I think all depictions of '7' have the line through the middle, meaning you don't have 27 circled. I think that's supposed to just be 2. (I have found 27 somewhere else where this rule is followed.)
And I don't think your number '1' is right. If you turn it the right way up, that would be backwards.
Also, good luck with 12, 19, 35, 41, 43 and 46. I found them to be quite sneaky. ;)

Comment: Thanks for your input @Timoris. Have you found all of them yet? I haven't had the time to finish as yet.

Comment: Yes, that's a rule for the sevens to make them clear. And yeah those are meant to be sneaky. :D